# How to make sure that every entry in an array is in a table?

Tags: mysql

I have a 'tags' table for an item management system.

I want to make sure that before inserting an item that the tags that are attached to the item are in the 'tags' table.

How do i check that every item in the 'tags' array is in the 'tags' table and if it isn't in the table, insert it into the table.

Thanks

Im using mySQL 5.5

Comment: How do you mean array, sql does not have arrays. Can you explain by example

Comment: There's nothing to be gained by 'checking first'

Comment: im using js to call sql statements so i need to use an array of tags, make sure each one is in the database and then insert other items which relate to these tags so need to have keys to be inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `UNIQUE` index on tag names, then use `INSERT IGNORE` to insert the tags:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100)
);
ALTER TABLE tags ADD UNIQUE INDEX uix_name (name);

INSERT IGNORE INTO tags(name) VALUES
('foo'),
('bar');
-- Affected rows: 2

INSERT IGNORE INTO tags(name) VALUES
('foo'),
('baz');
-- Affected rows: 1

INSERT IGNORE INTO tags(name) VALUES
('bar'),
('baz');
-- Affected rows: 0
```

This will insert only the missing tags in the table.